# How to plot QAbstractItemModel using QCustomPlot

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel, qcustomplot

Is there a direct way to pass `QAbstractItemModel` to [QCustomPlot](http://qcustomplot.com/)?
Currently I am defining two `QVector<double>` for `Xval` and `yVal`. When I have to plot, I update these two vectors from `QAbstractItemModel` to launch the plot function.

Is there any way that [QCustomPlot](http://qcustomplot.com/) can accept `QAbstractItemModel`?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is not a direct support for `QAbstractItemModel` in `QCustomPlot`. I am not sure how you expect `QCustomPlot` to draw contents of a `QAbstractItemModel`. As you know the model could be a simple model or a complex one or even hierarchical. That's two much for a simple 2D plot like `QCustomPlot`. But there seems to be a way to assign data of a subclass of `QAbstractItemModel` to `QCustomPlot` and that's using [QCPDataMap](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPGraph.html#a2f58436df4f86a2792b776a21642b3d9).

You should populate the data of your model in `QCPDataMap` and assign it to plot. That's something like :

```
QCPDataMap *data = new QCPDataMap();

for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    data->insertMulti(data->constEnd(), x[i], QCPData(x[i], y[i]));

plot->graph()->setData(data);
```

You can generate `QCPDataMap` in your model using x and y values and assign it's pointer to plot.

Comment: `QCustomPlot` certainly could support table models. That it doesn't is not out of necessity, but out of lack of time/willpower/manpower. It'd be an easy thing to do.